# How to receive push notification in angularJs web Application with FCM.?

Tags: angularjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show push notification on angular web app when Server sends a message via FCM.
What would be the best way to approach this, is there an Angular plugin for this (which I must admit I cannot find myself).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) on a MVC Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064803/implementing-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-a-mvc-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

Following [Firebase Javascript Web Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) which requires you to do the following all you will have left to do is expose the obejcts and perform the initialization in your appropriate angular artifacts.

**Updated 1/28/2019**: <strike>Make sure you add script tags to get firebase-messaging bundle `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>` 
 but if you have browserify etc you can following their article and samples fully.</strike>

The raw JavaScript is as below:-

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

You could do this initialization in your config block - something like below. Remember `firebase` is a global object.

```
app.config(function() {
      var config = {
        apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
        authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
});
```

You can also create background message handler in some service or same config block according to [firebase-messaging-sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js) Here is the gits of it:-

```
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 // [END initialize_firebase_in_sw]
 **/
// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// [START background_handler]
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: The firebase-messaging.js should not be required since it is contained in firebase.js. The background message handler is required, otherwise the firebase.messaging().getToken() will not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Firebase [Cloud Messaging Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging) example. Be careful to include the file firebase-messaging-sw.js in your /dist folder during deployment.